# How do I calculate Big Omega Notation for a function?

Tags: asymptotics

I was looking at the definition of Big Omega:
\begin{align}
\Omega(g(n)) &= \{ f(n): \text{ there exist positive constants }c \text{ and }n_0 \\
           &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{ such that }0 \le cg(n) \le f(n) \text{ for all }n \ge  n_0 \}
\end{align}

I have a function $\frac{n^2+n}2$ to prove that it belongs to $\Omega(n^3)$.

I started like this

$cn^3 \le \frac{n^2+n}2$ but I am not quite sure how do I get $c$, if I pick $n=1$ I get $c\le 1$ but what is the better way of proving this?

Comment: It is not true that $\frac{n^2 +n}{2} \in \Omega(n^3)$. However, $\frac{n^2 +n}{2} \in \mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

Comment: @Gary why it isn't? for  n=1  I get c<= 1 and if I increase n I get c smaller value but greateer than 0

Comment: The $c$ should remain fixed for all sufficiently large values of $n$. Otherwise, the concept would not make much sense.

Comment: so we have to find a c such as the expression will always be true no matter how much n increases?

Comment: Yes, you want a $c$ such that the inequality holds for all $n$ from a certain point (this point is indicated by $n_0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have $\frac{n^2 +n}{2} \in \Omega(n^3)$, you need a positive constant $c$ s.t. for $n\geq n_0$ you have

$$0<cn^3 \leq \frac{n^2 +n}{2}$$

But

$$\frac{n^2 +n}{2n^3} =\frac 12\left(\frac 1n + \frac 1{n^2}\right)\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

So, there is no such $c$. Hence, $\frac{n^2 +n}{2}\not \in \Omega(n^3)$

Comment: isn't that big O?

Comment: so also big Theta wouldn't be true right?

Comment: @Alfred Exactly, it cannot be in big theta, because it is not in big omega.